# Set MS Office 365 display language ditterently for different apps?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, language-pack

Have Office 365 Professional. Wish to have display language Swedish in all apps but Excel to be able to use Functions in English (who got the stupid idea to translate function names anyhow?). Any way to do this or must I choose between running all of Office in English or relearn Functions in Swedish?

Comment: Googling seems to suggest that there might be an English language pack you can install. Otherwise have a look in the Options menu where there is a "Language" tab where you can add or edit the languages you can use.

Comment: Looking at that language options menu (in Office 2010) it seems that you can set up "per application" language defaults which suggests that it would be what you want.