# MS Office change language for only one app

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

I know how to change the language for all of Office suite apps. What I'm looking for is some way to leave all Office apps (Excel, Word, Outlook etc.) displayed in English and specifically change the display language of MS Access to Hebrew (only Access nothing else!)

Does anyone no a way to do that? maybe some addon / third party app to assist?

p.s.
I saw this post [Set MS Office 365 display language ditterently for different apps?](https://superuser.com/questions/1262908/set-ms-office-365-display-language-ditterently-for-different-apps) - but it ends nowhere

Comment: The Options that are required to be set apply to all Office applications.  What you want is not possible, the comment in the other question isn't actually correct.

Comment: Try to install Access standalone version.

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall the language packs and install them again, and on the installation, use the customized installation, therefore leave all "not available" but only leave on default the office application in which you need the desired language, for example, you need your Access to hebrew, so, go to programs and characteristics and choose "microsoft office language pack 20xx - Hebrew" some words may vary, and then run the setup for the language pack again and on customized install, put everything to "not available" except access
Finally just change the display language on the settings, and the language will only be displayed for the application you installed the language pack for, as the language is not available for any of them.
Hope it helps to anyone reading this